# AmazonS3Client is deprecated how to get s3client object with using credential

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

For getting s3 client object i am using below code.

```
BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(key, S3secretKey); 
AmazonS3 s3Client =AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
```

Getting below errors

Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a builder you need to provide your S3 bucket region using builder method, like `.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)`

Answer (score 4):

I had to change to:

```
AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                         .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                         .withForceGlobalBucketAccess(true)
                         .build();
```

to emulate the "old" way (i.e. new AmazonS3Client() )

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with the 1.11.98 version of the sdk, in your code, you would do:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

And you need to have ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config files:

~/.aws/credentials contents:

```
[pca]
aws_access_key_id = KDDDJGIzzz3VVBXYA6Z
aws_secret_access_key = afafaoRDrJhzzzzg/Hhcccppeeddaf

[deault]
aws_access_key_id = AMVKNEIzzzNEBXYJ4m
aws_secret_access_key = bU4rUwwwhhzzzzcppeeddoRDrJhogA
```

~/.aws/config contents:

```
[default]
region = us-west-1

[pca]
region = us-west-1
```

Make sure they're readable, and that you export a profile if you have multiple as above before starting your service:

```
alper$ export AWS_PROFILE="pca"
```

There's a good description [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html)